# Wrapper Library for Android Camera API

Tags: android, camera

Is there a wrapper library for the Android Camera API that covers all the pitfalls in the different API versions (f.e. checks the version if front camera, auto-focus or flash light is available and provides controls for it in the UI) and all the hardware bugs in different handsets ?

Comment: Ask me again in six months. If I haven't found one, I'll probably write one.

Comment: Same problem here. I am thinking about just writing my own.  Its kind of crazy we havent really seen this yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare Found one?

Comment: @Qw4z1: Wrote one: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Comment: I haven't faced any hardware bugs on my test devices yet. Do the bugs occur on specific versions/models?

Comment: @CommonsWare Your library looks amazing! How do you include it in an android maven project?

Comment: @Benny: If Maven has been updated to support AARs, my repo has pointers to a Maven repo and artifact name, in the Gradle instructions. If Maven still only supports apklib, you're out of luck, other than manually managing the JARs yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/Glamdring/EasyCamera

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who stumbles here searching a camera library, there is **CWAC-Camera library** which helps reducing the somehow extensive Android Camera API and, at the same time, bringing better support across various devices:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Hope this helps!

**Edited**

CWAC-Camera library is deprecated

use this second version

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2

Comment: cwac-camera is now deprecated. Better to use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2  I use this for my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.getintouch.play

Comment: One would expect it to be a view but unfortunately, Intent based only.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't so ambicious, the Square Camera is a very simple approach to task, and seems to work nicely: https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera

No video record, no options, but good focus and the square approach avoid issues with resolution and portrait/landscape modes. Seems to work on devices where CWAC2 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem right now. I just can't get my head around the fact that it is so hard to do such a simple thing on Android: taking a picture and saving it to the device.

Anyroad: I just stumbled upon this library. I didn't try it yet. Maybe it helps you: https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project

Comment: It doesn't fix any bugs or pitfalls actually. It's a wrapper with some basic options like solarize etc.

Comment: Taking a low level picture from a *unknow* device camera will never be really a "simple thing". Was hard on desktop Java as well.

But if you just need take a picture and nothing more, is fairly simple indeed. Just send an Intent with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action and deal with result.